# Does flash always post a "Filename" parameter when doing a file upload?

Tags: flash, file-upload, uploadify, swfupload

I have tried two flash upload components, swfupload and uploadify, and both seem to generate POSTs with a "Filename" parameter. My problem is that the service I'm posting to has a strictly specified set of allowed parameters and Filename is not one of them.

So, is it at all possible to remove this parameter from the post?

Comment: What service are you posting to? What are the allowed parameters?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload()) reveals that you can change the `uploadDataFieldName`, which is by default `"Filedata"`, by setting the second parameter of the `upload()` method. Docs doesn't say anything about the `Filename` parameter though, so I guess that's a no.

Comment: I thought the question was about swfupload and uploadify (which are 3rd-party products), not the AS3 FileReference class.

Comment: @rich I believe swfupload and uploadify use `FileReference` class in the background. Unless they are targeting only Flash player 10 users, there is no way to access the file content inside the SWF itself.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the docs and it says: 

"The following sample HTTP POST request is sent from Flash Player to a server-side script if no parameters are specified: 
...
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"
...

Comment: Even if you specify parameters, it still sends the "Filename" parameter.  Worse yet, it sends the filename redundantly as part of the "filedata" parameter as well: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filedata"; filename="filename.zip"`